# Long running php process with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I created a `Symfony 3` command that is expected to run for days (or even weeks). It uses `Doctrine 2` for reading some initial data and for writing the execution status from time to time. The SQLs are expected to take few milliseconds.

My concern is that the whole process will eventually crash if the MySQL connection closes due to inactivity.

Question: **is Doctrine keeping the database connection open between `flush` calls?** Or, is it reconnecting every time `flush` is called?

Comment: Unfortunately, bulk processing does not apply in my case. I plan to update database only when I start and when I end the process (which could take days). 
The process is running long but it's handling large content from disk/s3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK Symfony will open up a connection to the database the first time Doctrine is used in your app and close it when the HTTP request is sent (or if you specifically tell Doctrine to close it). Once connected, Doctrine will have the connection active until you explicitly close it (and will be active before, during and after `flush()`)

In your case you should probably open and close the db connection explicitly when you need it. Something like the following code could solve your problem:

```
// When you need the DB
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection $connection
 */
$connection = $this->get('doctrine')->getConnection();
// check if the connection is still active and if not connect to the db
if(!$connection->isConnected()) {
    $connection->connect();
}
// Your code to update the database goes after this.

your code

// Once you're done with the db update - close the connection.
if($connection->isConnected()) {
    $connection->close(); // close the db connection;
}
```

This will avoid db connection timeouts and etc, however you should be quite careful with memory leaks if this script will be running as long as you're saying. Using Symfony might not be the best approach to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply ping the connection every 1000 seconds, less than MySQL's connection limit.

Best thing to do would be to run a supervising process (eg. [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)), which would restart the process as soon as your app stops. Then you can simply tell your script to exit before the connection is dropped (as it's a configured value, in MySQL for instance it's the `wait_timeout` variable). Supervising process will notice your app is dead and will restart it.

Comment: "you are aware that PHP sucks as long running process" this may be true in PHP4 era. I have production code running PHP7.2 for TPS and processes are running for months without any problems.